# Processing response from telnet command

Tags: ruby, telnet

I telnet into my test device, and after logging in, issue a command which gives me ten lines of response. I want to assign these ten lines to an array or any data structures to validate the response. E.g., my response looks like below. I want to check bits and pieces within the list of lines. I might want to check `192`, `brown` and `0903`.

> I have a 192 blocks of sand , which are 
>  green brown
>  yellow is
>   a color of grain 
>  11 0909 0903

Following is my sample code. If I assign the result as array, all data are assigned as first element.

```
require 'net/telnet'

i = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => '192.111.214.16',
  "Port" => 23,
  "Output_log" => "output.log", # default: nil (no output)
  "Dump_log"   => "dump.log",   # default: nil (no output)
  "Prompt"     => /[#>]/ , # default: /[$%#>] \z/n
  "Telnetmode" => true,         # default: true
  "Timeout"    => 100,           # default: 10
)

i.login("admin", "pass") { |c| print c }
result = i.cmd("String" => "status", "Match" => /a#/)
print result
```

Comment: Does the response always come back in the same structure or can the data shift?

Comment: same structure is intended. I receive in same structure only, easy for comparing preset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html#method-i-cmd), `cmd` returns a string containing the complete output.

So you should be able to use `split` to get it as an array containing one string per line:

```
result = i.cmd("String" => "status", "Match" => /a#/).split("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked perfectly .split("\n") gave me my required response

Comment: You're welcome. I've added the argument value "\n" to my answer (since it is necessary if the response contains spaces) - thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: I have another question here. what data type will the array elements be of? I tried to compare each element with the matching string, it always fails.

Comment: nearly what i need, but i dont want the trying 10.10.10.1 and connected to 10.10.10.1 in my logfile, just the response *after* the login

Comment: @PeterCore Please ask a separate question on StackOverflow for this.